# mysql row into variable using while loop

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to output data into an xml file, everything is working fine except it's only saving the last record fetched.

The following query is used:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mileage FROM cars WHERE make ='bmw' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 3");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$result = $row['mileage'];
}
```

My question is how do I make it so each record is saved in 3 seperate variables so I can output those 3 variables into an xml file. I am also trying to fetch only the last 3 rows sorted by the last date and last time so not sure if the query is correct for doing that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use folowing;

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mileage FROM cars WHERE make ='bmw' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 3");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$result[] = $row['mileage'];
}
```

You can `foreach` $result and construct your xml.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly: Don't use the mysql_* functions! They are obsolete and you should use [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead.

Secondly: The easiest thing to do is to construct an array containing the results.

```
$result = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mileage FROM cars WHERE make ='bmw' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 3");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $result[] = $row['mileage'];
}
```

The results of your query are now contained in `$result[0]`, `$result[1]` and `$result[2]`. (If you use PDO the code does not look very different.)

Comment: Thanks, yeah it is working now using $result[0], $result[1] and $result[2].

Answer (score 1):

```
$result=array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT mileage FROM cars WHERE make ='bmw' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 3");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
$result[]  = $row['mileage'];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try saving the output as an array instead.

```
$array[]=$value;
```

will push the $value inside the $array array.

Answer (score -1):

get yourself a *function*

```
function dbGetCol($sql){
  $ret = array();
  $res = mysql_query($sql) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." ".$sql);
  if ($res) {
    while($row = mysql_fetch_row($res)){
      $ret[] = $row[0];
    }
  }
  return $ret;
}
```

and then just call it

```
$data = dbGetCol("SELECT mileage FROM cars WHERE make ='bmw' ORDER BY date DESC, time DESC LIMIT 3");
```

Comment: Thanks I guess I'll use this next time.

Comment: LOL. What next time you are talking about? If you have no idea what is a function and how to use it - just say that, no need to hesitate :)